# How to inspect "this" object in Visual Studio while debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

When you debug your program, and for example you set a breakpoint as in here:

```
void foo(string s)
{
  (*) if (s=="bar")
  ...
}
```

(*) denotes breakpoint

you can move mouse cursor over "s" and inspect the content of it.

**The question is** how to do the same (i.e. inspect object) but not any argument or variable, but "this" object?

My case: I get exception at some point, I trace call stack, and let's say I would like to inspect "this" object of the 4th method of the call stack (for example).

Comment: Just type "this".  Have you tried it?

Comment: Don't you mean something what is available in the Autos panel? See this image: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_GRyemvn7ChM/SvAATCMaJCI/AAAAAAAABQo/0eGvlBp95LY/Autos.jpg

Comment: @321X, no, I meant the code pane, when you move mouse over variable or argument, field, etc. But sllev answer is perfect for me, so case closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Quick Watch Window

   - Right click in any place of window
   - In menu select "Quick Watch"
   - In text field enter `this`
   - Press OK
2. Add Watch Window

   - Visual Studio menu -> `Debug -> Windows -> Watch -> Watch 1`
   - In opened Watch WIndow type in `Name` field `this` and press Enter
3. Immediate Window

   - Visual Studio menu -> `Debug -> Windows -> Immediate Window`
   - Type `this` and press Enter

Comment: Beauty. I focused too much on tip-inspect on mouse cursor over the object. Thank you very much.

Comment: A quick way to open the Quick Watch is to press Ctrl+D followed by Ctrl+Q. Saves a few mouse clicks!